# Node - Run code after return statement

Tags: node.js, meteor

Is there any way to run a block of code after the return of a function in node js?

Something like this:

```
   function f() {
         #do stuff
         #return result
         #do more stuff
    }
```

Comment: Why you want to do this?

Comment: @yueyou because the result doesn't depend on the last block of code, and that block of code is making function slower

Comment: It seems no way to run after you return

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that in the way that you show.  `return` exits from the containing function and statements immediately after the `return` statement do not execute (in fact they are dead code).

(Per your comments) If what you're really trying to do is to execute something "out of band" that the rest of the function (including the return value) does not depend upon, you could schedule that code to run later.  For example, you could use `setTimeout()`, `process.nextTick()` or `setImmediate()`.

```
function f() {
     // do stuff
     setTimeout(function() {
         // do some stuff here that will execute out of band
         // after this function returns
     }, 0);
     return someVal;
}
```

There are legit uses for things like this where you want to execute something soon, but you don't want it to get in the way of the current operation.  So, you'd essentially like to queue it to execute when the current activity is done.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is No. After you return the function will stop execution. You can consider using a better flow control to run the code like `Async/Await` or `Promise`

`You use the return statement to stop execution of a function and return the value of expression.` according to the following doc 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/return-statement-javascript